# Error while installing aws iot node-red package on armv5tejl

Tags: node-red, aws-iot

I have a `armv5tejl` device where i have the following versions of 
node `v0.10.40` and npm `1.4.28`

I am trying to install the following package - 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-aws-iot

I had previously used the same config and had successfully installed this contrib module and worked with AWS IoT. 
Now when i try to install the same module it throws me some warning messages as follows -

```
npm WARN engine aws-iot-device-sdk@2.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.40","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN engine mqtt@2.13.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.40","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm WARN unmet dependency /opt/node-red/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/tar-pack requires debug@'~2.2.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /opt/node-red/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/debug,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.6.3
```

Now when i open node red i don't find any nodes for aws-iot. I checked the node-red log file and found the following -

```
/opt/node-red/node_modules/node-red-contrib-aws-iot/node_modules/aws-iot-device-sdk/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/websocket-stream/server.js:6
class Server extends WebSocketServer{
^^^^^
```

I want to use the same module. How can i fix this and get it working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your NodeJS to at least v4.0.0. (you are currently using v0.10.40 not v0.4.10 you mentioned at the start of the question and is also no longer supported)

It looks like the node has been updated since you last installed it and now uses language features that are only available in NodeJS v4.0.0 or later.

If you REALLY can not update the NodeJS version then you may be able to force the old version to install by using the '@' syntax. But without knowing why the node was updated there is no guarantee that the old version will continue to work properly.

Comment: Oh yes. you are right. Corrected the node version in the question. Ok i can try to install using the @ syntax first. I had tried to update NodeJS but it totally corrupts the system somehow and everything stops working

Comment: Any nodes with a binary component will need to be rebuilt after upgrading node.

Comment: Ok this is strange. I installed the same module in a rPi and copied the contents of the package from the node_modules folder to this device and it works

Comment: That is not a long term solution, you REALLY need to get to a supported version of NodeJS